# KDE CIFS mount. Can copy files with mc but dolphin won't

Tags: kde, samba, cifs, dolphin

I have a samba/cifs mount that is accessible 
r/w from the commandline (mc).

The KDE filemanager dolphin shows the content
 of the samba share, but gives me a 
"no space left on device" when I try to copy files on it.

The mount line in /etc/fstab contains the uid and gid
( uid=1000,gid=100 ). Could this be the problem.

Any ideas? thanks!

Comment: What happens when you use a straight `cp`? I'm not sure if useful, but you could also try using the built-in command line in Dolphin (View > Panels > Terminal).

Comment: Midnight commander copy worked fine. Cp might, too. Will try later to confirm

Comment: yes, cp works. just copy with kde filemanager dolphin doesn't

Comment: I guess it's probably a Dolphin bug then. FWIW I've had problems before when I attempt to move things into the trash. I get a similar message. I suppose Dolphin gets confused with the amount of available space on certain file systems.